# Finding probability density function OF cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $X$ be a continuous r.v. with p.d.f. $f$ and c.d.f. $F$. Suppose that $f$ is continuous and that $f(x)>0 \, \forall \, x\in \mathbb{R} $. Compute the p.d.f of the r.v. $F(X)$.

I tried the usual method. Let $Y = F(X)$. $F_Y (y) = P(\int_{-\infty}^{X} f(t) dt \leq y)$. But unlike usual, I don't know how to write this as $P(X\leq g(y))$ for some function $g$. The fundamental theorem of calculus is probably not useful.

Edit: The usual method is as follows: Given a r.v. $Y$, we find the c.d.f. $F_Y$ of $Y$. $\frac{dF_Y}{dy}$ is the p.d.f. of $Y$

Please give a hint. Thanks

Comment: The PDF $f$ of the CDF $F$ is simply the derivative $F'$ . I cannot make sense of the equations you are calling the usual method.

Comment: @Kurt G. pl check the edit.

Comment: Under your conditions, $F(x)$ is continuous and strictly increasing and so invertible.  So the usual way to find the cdf is to say $P(Y \le y) $ $= P(F(X) \le y) $ $= P(X \le F^{-1}(y)) $ $= F(F^{-1}(y))$ $=y$ when $0 < y < 1$.  The density of $Y$ is then obvious

Comment: @Herny That solves the question. Thanks.